# Why does an answer appear in "faded" text?

Tags: support

An accepted answer with three downvotes (now deleted) appeared "faded" but when my mouse pointer hovered over the answer, the text appeared normal.

What does the faded text signify?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166932/why-the-downvoted-answers-are-blurred

Answer (score 9):

Answers with a total score of **-3 or less automatically render faded**
until you tickle them with your mouse.  That's independent of the
*accepted* thingy. I think the reason is to visually mark them as not
exactly useful at a glance.

<sup>Disclaimer: I couldn't find an official source or help page for
this behaviour, so this is just my personal observation and experience.</sup>

Comment: This could be related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166932/why-the-downvoted-answers-are-blurred?rq=1.